# Jsoup and Listview Programming

Tags: android, jsoup

**Java Codes**

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

  setContentView(R.layout.announcement);

  Document document = Jsoup.parse("url");
  String element = document.select("tbody").select("div.m_ltitle").text();

  arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
  arrayList.add(element);


  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);


  listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.announcementlist);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

          String str = (String)adapter.getItem(position);
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
  });
  }
}
```

"Well, I'm really a freshman on android"(sorry for low-quality questions),
and making an parse Activity using Jsoup.
I made jsoup to parse the texts by selecting codes by tags, and then add to listview that is located on R.layout.announcement(listview id: announcementlist).
However it repeats that applications has stopped.

Any suggestions will be thankful.

**These are the logcat**

08-17 17:16:58.383: D/AndroidRuntime(10404): Shutting down VM

08-17 17:16:58.393: W/dalvikvm(10404): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419efce0)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404): Process: com.example, PID: 10404

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404): android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.Announcement that is not a Fragment

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.example.MainActivity$ProductTabListener.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:98)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1105)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException

08-17 17:16:58.393: E/AndroidRuntime(10404):    ... 17 more

**Last Console**

Starting activity com.example.MainActivity on device 76250880

ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }

Comment: Paste your error log

Comment: @bhargavg pasted. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using String array:

String[] values =new String[1];// size according to your need

String element = document.select("tbody").select("div.m_ltitle").text();

values[0]=element;

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
(this,android.R.layout.layout.simple_list_item_1,  values);

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.announcementlist);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Did you meant to replace String Element ~ listView.setAdapter(adapter);? R.layout.layout error detected. Still error placing while executing. I've attached logcat and console records. Thank you.